# Aggregating Pandas DF - Losing Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to aggregate a pandas df in a way an excel pivot table would. I have one quantitative variable called "Count". I would like the same qualitative variables to combine and the "Count" data to sum.

However, when I am trying to do this with the below code, I see that I am somehow losing data. Any idea why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

I expect the number of rows to decrease but the total sum of the "Count" column shouldn't change.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `NaN`s in your dataframe, they won't be included in your `groupby` operation, and thus the data for those rows will not be summed.